# テーブルを作る判断基準を教えて欲しいです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

メッセージアプリを作成中です。
１対１でメッセージをやり取りしようとしています。

やりたいことは、ユーザー一覧画面でユーザーを選択して、選択したユーザーの詳細画面でメッセージ投稿して、そのユーザー詳細画面でメッセージを表示したいです。
ユーザー詳細画面で送信ユーザーと受信ユーザーがどちらもメッセージを見れるようにしたいです。
（よくあるチャットアプリのようなイメージです）

Userモデル（Userテーブル）とMessageモデル（Messageテーブル）の２つだけあります。
この２つのテーブルでできることでしょうか。

それとももう一つテーブルが必要でしょうか。その際、なぜ必要なのか教えていただけますでしょうか。
（テーブルを作成する判断基準を教えて欲しいです）

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
      
end
```

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = User.find(1)
    @sent_messages = @user.sent_messages.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
  
  def new
  end
  
  def create
params[current_user.id], recipient_id: params[:recipient_id])
    @message = Message.new(message: params[:message], sender_id: params[current_user.id], recipient_id: params[:id])

      if @message.save
        flash[:notice] = "メッセージ作成に成功しました"
        redirect_to "/users/#{:id}"
      else
        flash[:error] = @message.errors.full_messages
        render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
  end
end
```

以下がMessageテーブルのカラムです。

```
Message.column_names
=> ["id", "message", "created_at", "updated_at", "sender_id", "recipient_id"]
```

以下がUserテーブルのカラムです。

```
User.column_names
=> 
["id",
 "email",
 "encrypted_password",
 "reset_password_token",
 "reset_password_sent_at",
 "remember_created_at",
 "name",
 "created_at",
 "updated_at"]
```

Answer (score 0):

作成しようとしているメッセージアプリは、UserモデルとMessageモデルを使用して、十分に実装可能です。追加のテーブルを作成する必要はありません。以下に、あなたの要件に基づいて、どのように実装を進めるべきかを説明してみます。外していたらごめんなさい。

### UserモデルとMessageモデルの関係

- Userモデルは、アプリケーションのユーザーを表します。
- Messageモデルは、ユーザー間でのメッセージを表します。このモデルには、送信者（sender_id）と受信者（recipient_id）の両方の情報が含まれます。

### ユーザー間のメッセージ交換

- ユーザーが他のユーザーを選択した際には、そのユーザーの詳細画面に移動し、メッセージを投稿できるようにします。
- 投稿されたメッージは、送信者と受信者の両方に表示される必要があります。
- この機能は、Messageモデルのsender_idとrecipient_idを用いて実装できます。

### MessagesControllerの実装

- createアクションでは、現在のユーザー（sender_id）と選択されたユーザー（recipient_id）を基にメッセージを作成します。
- 作成したメッセージは、適切なユーザーの詳細画面にリダイレクトして表示します。

### コードの修正点

- createアクション内でのメッセージの保存方法に誤りがあります。正しくは`Message.new(message: params[:message], sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: params[:recipient_id])`のようになります。
- indexアクションでは、現在のユーザーが送信したメッセージのみを取得しています。受信したメッセージも同様に取得する必要があります。

### 追加のテーブルが不要な理由

- 既存のUserモデルとMessageモデルだけで、ユーザー間のメッセージ交換の要件を満たせるためです。
- Messageモデルは、送信者と受信者の情報を持っているので、どのメッセージがどのユーザー間で交換されたかを追跡することができます。

### テーブル作成の判断基準

- 新しい機能が既存のモデルで実現できない場合、または既存のモデルの責務が不適切に拡大する場合に新たなテーブルを作成することを考えます。
- 例えば、グループチャット機能を追加する場合、新たなGroupモデルが必要になるかもしれません。しかし、現在の要件ではその必要はありません。

以上でアプリの基本的なメッセージ交換機能は実装できるはずです。必要に応じてUIや追加機能を検討してみてください。